# Writing out a new line in a file while encrypting it with ECC - Python

Tags: python

**Hi!**

I have a simple code, which is using ECC encryption. I want to write out an encrypted text while putting a new line in it.

```
from ecies.utils import generate_eth_key, generate_key
from ecies import encrypt, decrypt

keyPair = generate_key()
secretKey = keyPair.secret
publicKey = keyPair.public_key.format(True)

with open(pathToFile, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(encrypt(publicKey, b"Hi!\nI want to put a new line here."))
    fp.close()
```

When I decrypt the file, I'll get this:

```
b"Hi!\nI want to put a new line here."
```

Decrypting goes like this:

```
with open(pathToFile, 'rb') as fp:
    global fileText
    fileText = fp.read()

print(decrypt(secretKey, fileText))
```

**So the question is simple, how can I write out some text with new lines while encrypting the text?**

Comment: Try to split your writing process in two parts, write the first line the the second separatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, it is working as expected:

```py
from ecies.utils import generate_eth_key, generate_key
from ecies import encrypt, decrypt

keyPair = generate_key()
secretKey = keyPair.secret
publicKey = keyPair.public_key.format(True)

with open('example.txt', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(encrypt(publicKey, b"Hi!\nI want to put a new line here."))

with open('example.txt', 'rb') as fp:
    decrypted_contents = decrypt(secretKey, fp.read())
    print(decrypted_contents.decode('utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
Hi!
I want to put a new line here.
```

> b"Hi!\nI want to put a new line here."

`b` means binary data. If you read file as a binary data (`open(... 'rb')`) you have to decode it

> with open(pathToFile, 'wb') as fp:
> 　fp.write(encrypt(publicKey, b"Hi!\nI want to put a new line here."))
> 　fp.close()

`fp.close()` is unnecessary here. `with` context manager doing it (closing file) automatically when `with` block ends.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to decode the whole content of the file in utf-8.